# How to mimic calling template-match with a parameter value?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm looking for a workaround on passing parameters to a template-match. I'm aware this isn't allowed within XPath, and therefore I'm looking for a 'plan B' solution.

This is what I wished would work :

Part 1 of xslt (2.0) :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Main/PageList/Page">
    <xsl:result-document href="{@ID}.xml">
        <Page ID="{@ID}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="theID" select="@ID"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </Page>
    </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
```

So fairly straightforward, don't bother about the tags used, what it does in essence is go through a node, and for each node it creates a single XML file. Each node starts with an ID, and it's this ID I'd like to make available for other templates. Unfortunately this works fine for named templates, but it doesn't work for matched ones (if I understood the theory correctly at least)

So below is what I'd like to see working :

```
<!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:param name="theID"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
            <xsl:with-param name="theID" select="$theID"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- lots of templates here doing what I want them to do -->

<!-- one template creating an issue -->

<xsl:template match="@src">
<!-- would be nice to know the current ID, but unfortunately this one stays empty... -->
<xsl:param name="theID"/>

<!-- clean current attribute a bit -->
<xsl:variable name="S1" select="replace(.,'\.\.\/','')"/>

<xsl:attribute name="src">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="contains($S1,'common')">
<!-- just use current value, don't bother about current ID -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$S1"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <!-- use ID parameter -->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($theID,'_',$S1)"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Don't look at the code as such, it's just a smaller part of the whole file, but the essence is that I want to use the ID parameter from my first part (match="/") inside the other template (match="@src"), but this seems to be rather complex.

Am I missing something ? If I'm just having bad luck and it's not possible indeed, would anyone have an advice how I could proceed ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can pass params to a template match in that way. May be applying the templates to node() is too generic and would match a template without param.

Comment: @empo : I've tried with removing the node() part but no real difference (might have misunderstood your point though, so not sure this is what you were aiming at). The parameter at the 'match' part remains empty, so if it should work I'm loosing it indeed somewhere in the process. I'll play around myself with a simpler version (my current XSLT is a bit more complex then the provided simplification of it)

Comment: I meant you probably need `xsl:apply-templates select="//@src"` where @src in place of node().

Comment: Good question, @Wokoman, +1: See my answer for an extensive explanation and for a complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem is here**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
  <xsl:with-param name="theID" select="@ID"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

the `select` attribute specifies that the processing should continue on any children nodes of the current node.

**However `node()` only selects children nodes (elements, text nodes, processing instructions and comments) -- not attributes**.

**Solution**:

1. **In order to directly cause processing of (all) attributes** of the current node, use:

--

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
  <xsl:with-param name="theID" select="@ID"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

.2. **In order to cause the processing only of the `src` attribute** of the current node use:

--

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@src">
  <xsl:with-param name="theID" select="@ID"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

.3. In order to process indirectly attributes tof the descendants of the current node, do:

--

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
  <xsl:with-param name="theID" select="@ID"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

**You also must ensure that any template that processes `node()` must have an `xsl:param` named `theID` and that it must pass this param in any `xsl:apply-templates` instruction**.

**In practice this means that you mus override all XSLT built-in templates**, because they aren't aware of your `xsl:param`.

Comment: I should have been more clear but in reality there are a lot of templates so calling src directly won't do the trick (in reality src is part of img element which in it's turn is doing stuff...) I realized by reading your feedback that my parameter just get's lost after first pass, so I thought to be smart and add it to the identity template instead (I modified my question a bit), but that doesn't help either. So, what obvious part am I overlooking here ? (changing to node()|attr* in my main template didn't make a difference, actually I ignore attributes at start on purpose)

Comment: @Wokoman: The `xsl:param` must be added to all templates and all of them should pass it with `xsl:with-param` to templates that they are applying (with `xsl:apply-templates`). It isn't enough to have the `xsl:param` only declared -- it also should be *passed* to the templates that are being applied.

Comment: Ok, was afraid of that :-) Just for my interest (and to appetite my learning hunger...) why isn't it enough to apply it to the identity template ? I always thought this would cascade through. If it's too complex too explain don't bother, as stated it would be just to understand better so I can avoid questions as this in future.

Comment: @Wokoman: As I say in my answer, whenever as result of `xsl:apply-templates` a matching template is selected for execution, and this template has no `xsl:param` declaration for your particular parameter, this breaks the chain. In particular any XSLT built-in template does this -- therefore, it would be safe to override all of the XSLT built-in templates with your own and all your templates must declare the necessary `xsl:param` and pass it to any other templates -- using `xsl:with-param` as a child of `xsl:apply-templates`.

Comment: @Wokoman: In case you can use XSLT 2.0, there is a special feature for this called `tunnel parameters`  --  this can be very convenient in cases like yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of

```
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
            <xsl:with-param name="theID" select="@ID"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
```

you rather want

```
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
            <xsl:with-param name="theID" select="parent::Page/@ID"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
```

assuming you want to pass on the `ID` attribute of the parent `Page` element.

On the other hand the `select="node()"` select any child nodes like child elements, child comment nodes, child text nodes, child processing instruction nodes, so I don't see why you later show a template matching an attribute node.

Comment: I've only shown one template, but in reality there are a few dozen and all do some reconstruction of the master data (page by page). The problem I have with the specific one mentioned here is that I need to reconstruct a path to an image, and there are 2 types of paths. For one I can just keep the value, but for others I need to have the current page (ID) to allow reconstruction of the actual path. I know I make it sound horribly complex but it's easier to see than describe (being non native speaker doesn't help either...). Using your change didn't make a difference unfortunately.